# H2 database does not accept a table name as named parameter

Tags: java, sql, h2

I'm having trouble when trying to run the following query against an in memory H2 (version 1.4.181) table:

```
Object result = hibernateSession
                  .createSQLQuery("show columns from :myTable")
                  .setString("myTable", "some_table")
                  .list();
```

This query causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ?[*] "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement: show columns from ? [42001-181]
...
...
...
```

I had done some debbuging and I found that during parse of query, the character "?" is tested to check if it is a valid identififer and it fails, causing the rise of exception (class org.h2.command.Parser, line 3027):

```
//currentToken is "?" at this point
if (currentTokenType != IDENTIFIER) {
        throw DbException.getSyntaxError(sqlCommand, parseIndex,
                "identifier");
    }
```

I think it is a bug. What you think?

Comment: SQL bind variables cannot reference metadata like that. You need to generate dynamic SQL like `show columns from some_table` and execute that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is quite normal. Hibernate could not possibly make a PreparedStatement of it.

Standard JDBC has many possibilities to query schemata and such, in a database vendor independant way.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = connection.getMetaData();
```

Then [getColumns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) can be used to receive a ResultSet of miscellaneous information.

Answer (score 1):

- You can try creating the required query instead of setting table name as named-parameter which won't work.

  > ```
  >  String sqlQuery = "show columns from " + tableName;
  >  Class<?> entity = Class.forName(entityName);
  >
  >  session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
  > ```
- Get the metadata information & then can retrieve required details from it.

  > String[] properties =
  >   sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entityClass).getPropertyNames();

  There are several other methods available to get meta information, can refer [ClassMetaData](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html)

*[I haven't checked Criteria API, will update if found anything relevant, you can try it]*